# WP7 Search on text box textchanged event

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a requirement in my wp7 application that I have to do partial match searching (multiple fields say firstname and lastname) on a list collection (say contact list) on every keypress on search text box and bind to listbox.   I have written linq query to get the result on texchanged event.  I am getting the result as expected, however it is not quick in response if I have more than 500 items in the collection.

I have posted the code below, I really appreciate if someone can help me out in tunning the performance issue.

```
private void TechChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IList<Contacts> results = searchcontList
            .Where(tb => tb.SearchText.Contains(textsearch.Text))
            .ToList();

    //"SearchText" is an attribute in contacts class which is concatination values of all the fields in contacts class
    listcontact.ItemsSource = results;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the AutoCompleteBox from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone : http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/autocompletebox-for-wp7-in-depth

Comment: Yes, but AutoCompleteBox is for suggestion will not fit for this requirement. I have to bind the result to a listbox which contains other columns also. Tobe more specific, let us say I have a collection of cotacts [firstname,lastname,emailid,phonenumber etc].  In this, i may have to search on anyfied by entering a text in search text box so that query does partial match and gives a matched result which I need to bind to listbox.  This I have to do it in textsearch box textchanged event.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite likely that you will not be able to improve performance of the search (i.e. the time taken to find the matching items and render them to the UI) - so you will nee to look at changing the way your application works to make it feel more responsive.

Do you really need to perform the search on *every* character entered into the `TextBox`?

A common solution to your problem is a concept called 'throttling' where you only perform your search when the user pauses in their text entry for a while. You can do this quite easily using Reactive Extensions as follows:

```
Observable.FromEvent<TextChangedEventArgs>(searchTextBox, "TextChanged")
          .Select(e => ((TextBox)e.Sender).Text)            
          .Where(text => text.Length > 2)
          .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))         
          .Subscribe(txt => // do your search here!);
```

The above code ensures that there are more than two characters before you start searching, and throttles to ensure that only one search is performed per 400 milliseconds. See the codeproject article I wrote for more details:

[Exploring Reactive Extensions (Rx) through Twitter and Bing Maps Mashups](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132966/Exploring-Reactive-Extensions-Rx-through-Twitter-a#handling)

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. I will try this method.

Comment: Finally I got to work with little bit of modification.  Please see the below code and let me know if any improvisation can be done.                                                                                                                                    Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(textsearch, "TextChanged")
            .Select(e => ((TextBox)e.Sender).Text)
            .Where(text => text.Length > 2)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
             .Subscribe(results => bindResult());

Comment: Finally I got to work with little bit of modification.  Please see the below code and let me know if any improvisation can be done.

Thanks a lot ColinE
                                                                                                
           Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(textsearch, "TextChanged")
            .Select(e => ((TextBox)e.Sender).Text)
            .Where(text => text.Length > 2)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
             .Subscribe(results => bindResult());